# Syndicated Posts when Updated Lose <p> HTML tags

Tags: posts, updates

When I have a syndicated post and then make an update to the syndicated copy (not original) it shows up in my blog as one long run-on paragraph. Nothing happens to the Visual or HTML data in that post, but once I click "Update" wordpress doesn't auto generate the necessary paragraph tags for the post. Is this a configuration problem or a bug with wordpress?

Comment: What do you mean by "syndicated" post? Are these posts elsewhere that you're importing into WordPress through an auto-blog / scraper plugin? And if so, what plugin are you using to do it?

Comment: Please mark your answer below as the solution, that works, you can mark your own answers as solution.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, these posts are imported into my blog using a plugin called FeedWordPress. After doing a little more research, it looks like the formatting filters option needs to be set to "Expose syndicate posts..." instead of "Protect syndicate posts...".

If the posts are protected, and I choose the Visual editing tab in the posts editor, then the < p > tags are removed from the HTML side resulting in one continuous paragraph.

Comment: Might be a good idea to contact the plugin author, as that doesn't sound like expected behavior. Glad you worked it out though.